# $\mathbb{P}^1$ embedded in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $\mathbb{P}^1$ is smoothly embedded as a real submanifold in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Is $\mathbb{P}^1$ then necessarily a *complex* submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^3$?

If this is not true in general, what can obstruct $\mathbb{P}^1$ from being a complex submanifold?

Supposing $\mathbb{P}^1$ is in fact a complex submanifold, what is the first Chern class $c_1(N)$ of the normal bundle $N$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$? Grothendieck's theorem gives that $N$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a_1)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a_2)$ where $a_1\geq a_2$ and $a_1+a_2=c_1(N)$. Can the normal bundle (i.e. $a_1$ and $a_2$) be determined in this case?

Comment: Certainly you can smoothly embed $S^2$ in $\Bbb R^6\subset\Bbb CP^3$ in lots of ways that won't be holomorphic. (Indeed, any holomorphic embedding would have to meet the $\Bbb P^2$ at infinity.) In the holomorphic case, $c_1(N)$ will depend on the degree of the embedding. If $\Bbb P^1$ is linearly embedded, it's going to be $2$, but, for example, for the cubic rational normal curve, it's going to be $10$.

Comment: @Ted: Thank you for your comment. If $\mathbb{P}^1$ is linearly embedded and $c_1(N)=2$, as you point out, how are $a_1$ and $a_2$ determined (we know they sum to 2 by Grothendieck's theorem).

Comment: They're both $1$ in this case. Think about the curve as a complete intersection of two planes, each of which has normal bundle $\mathscr O(1)$.

Comment: @Ted: Suppose a smooth degree-1 embedding $i:\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^3$ is not necessarily holomorphic, but does induce a holomorphic structure on the normal bundle. Then by Grothendieck's theorem $N=\mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(2-a)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is it still true that $a=1$?

Comment: How can the normal bundle have a holomorphic structure without the tangent bundle's having one?

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote wasn't clear. I meant that the pullback bundle $i^{\ast}T\mathbb{P}^3$ has a holomorphic structure (this happens, for example, for the pullback bundle of a pseudoholomorphic curve in an almost complex manifold). When $i$ is an embedding, the pullback bundle splits as the sum of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^1$ (which is $\mathcal{O}(2))$ and the normal bundle. Since $i^{\ast}T\mathbb{P}^3$ has a holomorphic structure, Grothendieck's theorem can be applied to $N$, and I am trying to determine which $N$ are possible.